# CDI TransactionInterceptor

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cdi

How can I capture the return of a interceptor CDI?

I create this:

```
@Interceptor
@Transactional
public class TransactionInterceptor implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private @Inject EntityManager manager;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object invoke(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Interceptor on!");      
        EntityTransaction trx = manager.getTransaction();
        Object obj = null;
        boolean criador = false;

        try {

            if (!trx.isActive()) {

                System.out.println("Iniciando transação ...");
                trx.begin();

                criador = true;
            }

            obj = context.proceed();

            if (trx != null && trx.isActive() && criador) {

                System.out.println("Comitando ...");
                trx.commit();

            }

            System.out.println("Finalizando interceptor ...");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("ERRO ENCONTRADO !");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

            if (trx != null && trx.isActive() && criador) {
                System.out.println("Rollback ...");
                trx.rollback();
            }

            System.out.println("Finalizando interceptor ...");

            return obj;
        } 

        return obj;
    }

}
```

And I would like to know if the transaction was commited or got rollback.

This is the main method:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public boolean salvar(Funcionario funcionario) {

    return funcionarioDAOImpl.salvar(funcionario);
}
```

How can I do this? I don't use spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way how to find out is to throw a `RuntimeException` from your interceptor after you roll back transaction. This is exactly what standard Java EE 7 `@Transactional` annotation does - if everything goes OK, transaction is committed and normal execution continues, or else transaction is rolled back and the calling code needs to catch an exception.

Code example:

```
@Interceptor
@Transactional
public class TransactionInterceptor implements Serializable {

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object invoke(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
        ...
        try {
          ...
        } catch (Exception e) {

            if (trx != null && trx.isActive() && criador) {
                trx.rollback();
                throw new RuntimeException("Transaction rolled back!", e);
            }

        } 

        return obj;
    }

}

// transactional bean
public class SalvarExecutor {
@Transactional
public boolean salvar(Funcionario funcionario) {
   return funcionarioDAOImpl.salvar(funcionario);
}
}

// caller CDI bean
public class Caller {
  @Inject SalvarExecutor executor;

  public void execute() {
    try {
      salvar.salvar();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // salvar was rolled back by the interceptor
    }
  }
}
```

You may introduce your own descendant of RuntimeException to be more specific in the catch block.

**Another option, although not so clean and readable:**

It is possible to create a separate `@RequestScoped` bean, which you might inject into both the interceptor and the caller bean. Then the interceptor might communicate indirectly with the caller - it may update intermediary request scoped bean, and afterwards the caller can retrieve the data from the very same bean.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do. The intercepted method doesn't know it is being intercepted, and there is no such thing as "the return (value?) of an interceptor".

In Java EE 7, there is the `javax.transaction.Transactional` interceptor binding which works out of the box. No need to write your own interceptor for JPA transactions.

Comment: i want to know if the trasaction got commit or rollback.